# SVM duality: set of hyperparameters not supported

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to train a SVM model on the Iris dataset. The aim is to classify Iris virginica flowers from other types of flowers. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris["data"][:, (2,3)] # petal length, petal width
y = (iris["target"]==2).astype(np.float64) # Iris virginica

svm_clf = Pipeline([
    ("scaler", StandardScaler()),
    ("linear_svc", LinearSVC(C=1, loss="hinge", dual=False))
])

svm_clf.fit(X,y)
```

My book, which is Aurelien Geron's "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn , Keras and TensorFlow", 2nd edition, at page 156 says:

> For better performance, you should set the `dual` hyperparameter to
>   `False`, unless there are more features than training instances

But If I set the `dual` hyperparameter to False, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Unsupported set of arguments: The combination of penalty='l2' and loss='hinge' are not supported when dual=False, Parameters: penalty='l2', loss='hinge', dual=False
```

It instead works if I set the `dual` hyperparameter to True.

Why is this set of hyperparameters not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L2 SVM with L1 loss (hinge) cannot be solving in the primal form. Only its dual form can be solved effectively. This is due to the limitation of the [LIBLINEAR](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/) library used by sklearn. If you want to solve the primal form of the L2 SVM you will have to use L2 loss (squared hinge) instead.

```
LinearSVC(C=1, loss='squared_hinge', dual=False).fit(X,y)
```

For mode details: [Link 1](https://www.quora.com/Liblinear-does-not-support-L1-regularized-L1-loss-hinge-loss-support-vector-classification-Why)